# Spring MVC: Retrieving uploaded files in JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am developing image upload system. The files are uploaded successfully into the directory and inserted into the database (MySQL). But the main problem is how to retrieve them from the directory, show them in JSP in `<img>`, and may be the most important question is where to save the uploaded files?

My project structure looks like this:

```
ProjectName
Java Resources
    - src/main/java
        - com.project.config
        - com.project.controller
        - com.project.model
    - src/main/resources
        - messages.properties

src
    - java
    - resources
    - webapp
        - WEB-INF
            - resources
                - css
                - js
                - icons
                - images (where I store the uploaded images)
        - views
```

Java config settings for static files (css,js etc.)

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
}
```

For now it works well when my files are in my project directory, but before I can retrieve them in JSP I have to clean my project in eclipse.

BUT:

As I understood from other posts is that I must not store the uploaded files in my project directory, because everytime the project is redeployed all the files will be gone (deleted). I have to store them in an external and HTTP accessible folder and to change `addResourceHandler` settings to the new directory.

But in that way of thoughts then where should my CSS, JS, Icons, Pictures (used in CSS) files be stored at, should I store them in the same folder I store my uploaded images or should they stay in my project folder? But if the files should be different directories then how `addResourceHandler` settings should be like?

What is the best approach for uploading and retrieving files with Spring MVC?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's depend on your system specification. If there is a lot of updating files then  it will be better to store the URL in the database and the files in some directory on the server. for more details here is a discussion about this dilemma : https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/better-saving-files-database-file-system/

Now to answer to how can we show them in jsp. you can try this code :

1) On server side :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getImage/{imagePath}")
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getImage(@PathVariable String imagePath, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        String rpath = "yourFileStoringDirectoryURL" + imagePath + ".jpg";
        Path path = Paths.get(rpath);
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        return data;
}
```

2) On client side :

```
 <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getImage/${urlToPicture}">
```